# How to split a string into a list of predefined substrings of different lengths?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a collection of predefined strings of unequal length, input a string, and split the string into occurrences of elements in the collection, the output should be unique for every input, and it should prefer the longest possible chunks.

For example, it should split s, c, h into different chunks, unless they are adjacent.

If "sc" appear together, it should be grouped into 'sc' and not as 's', 'c', similarly if "sh" appears then it must be grouped into 'sh', if "ch" appears then it should be grouped into 'ch', and finally "sch" should be grouped into 'sch'.

I only know `string.split(delim)` splits on specified delimiter, and `re.split('\w{n}', string)` splits string into chunks of equal lengths, both these methods don't give the intended result, how can this be done?

Pseudo code:

```py
def phonemic_splitter(string):
    phonemes = ['a', 'sh', 's', 'g', 'n', 'c', 'e', 'ch', 'sch']
    output = do_something(string)
    return output
```

And example outputs:

```
phonemic_splitter('case') -> ['c', 'a', 's', 'e']
phonemic_splitter('ash') -> ['a', 'sh']
phonemic_splitter('change') -> ['ch', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e']
phonemic_splitter('schane') -> ['sch', 'a', 'n', 'e']
```

Comment: can you please explain what is the input and output required question in confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
def phonemic_splitter(s, phonemes):
    phonemes = sorted(phonemes, key=len, reverse=True)
    result = []
    while s:
        result.append(next(filter(s.startswith, phonemes)))
        s = s[len(result[-1]):]
    return result
```

This solution relies on the fact that `phonemes` contains a list of all the possible phonemes that can be found within the string `s` (otherwise, `next` could raise an exception).

One could also speed up this solution by implementing a binary search to be used in place of `next`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex:

```
import re 
cases=['case', 'ash', 'change', 'schane']

for e in cases:
    print(repr(e), '->', re.findall(r'sch|sh|ch|[a-z]', e))
```

Prints:

```
'case' -> ['c', 'a', 's', 'e']
'ash' -> ['a', 'sh']
'change' -> ['ch', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e']
'schane' -> ['sch', 'a', 'n', 'e']
```

You could incorporate into your function this way:

```
import re 

def do_something(s, splits):
    pat='|'.join(sorted(
                   [f'{x}' for x in splits if len(x)>1],         
                    key=len, reverse=True))+'|[a-z]'
    return re.findall(pat, s)

def phonemic_splitter(string):
    phonemes = ['a', 'sh', 's', 'g', 'n', 'c', 'e', 'ch', 'sch']
    output = do_something(string, phonemes)
    return output
```